# Adding the Table markdown from [Documentation] to Q&A

Tags: feature-request, questions, documentation, markdown

On the [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) section, we can make our own tables with the following markup:

```
| Column | Column |
| ------ | ------ |
| Cell   | Cell   |
```

Using an example from SQL Server AdventureWorks, we can use the following markup to create the table below:

```
|LocationID |Name                                               |CostRate              |Availability                            |ModifiedDate           |
|---------- |-------------------------------------------------- |--------------------- |--------------------------------------- |-----------------------|
|1          |Tool Crib                                          |0.00                  |0.00                                    |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|2          |Sheet Metal Racks                                  |0.00                  |0.00                                    |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|3          |Paint Shop                                         |0.00                  |0.00                                    |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|4          |Paint Storage                                      |0.00                  |0.00                                    |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|5          |Metal Storage                                      |0.00                  |0.00                                    |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|6          |Miscellaneous Storage                              |0.00                  |0.00                                    |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|7          |Finished Goods Storage                             |0.00                  |0.00                                    |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|10         |Frame Forming                                      |22.50                 |96.00                                   |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|20         |Frame Welding                                      |25.00                 |108.00                                  |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|30         |Debur and Polish                                   |14.50                 |120.00                                  |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|40         |Paint                                              |15.75                 |120.00                                  |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|45         |Specialized Paint                                  |18.00                 |80.00                                   |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|50         |Subassembly                                        |12.25                 |120.00                                  |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
|60         |Final Assembly                                     |12.25                 |120.00                                  |2002-06-01 00:00:00.000|
```

[image: AdventureWorks.Production.Location Table Markup]

This markup does not work on the Q&A portion of the site.

This is very clean-looking, and easy-to-use.  Having this markup would (at the very least) provide an option to make questions in the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) section much more readable.

Comment: Nit: I presume they don't allow tables because nested tables are a bullcrap. Unlike docs where they use containers like div and span for everything, on the Q&A they use tables... tables I said!

Comment: It would be helpful for questions or answers to `Excel` sheets as well. Otherwise you have to make cumbersome screenshots.

Comment: "Closed as off-topic" is wrong or lazy. This is a valid feature request and should be addressed as such.