# Implement the table option to the stack overflow markdown editing tool

Tags: feature-request, editor

Can you please implement the **Table** option which is available in the Documentation Beta - Example section to the Stack Overflow markdown editing tool also.

It will helpful mainly for the SQL related questions.

[image: Table - editing tool]

Comment: @MichaelGaskill: My question is not related to how to create table, it is feature-request to implement the existing option.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill: The questions linked by you are raised in 2014 and it was declined. But the table option in documentation beta is introduced in 2016.

Comment: [Adding the Table markdown from Documentation to Q&A](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328989/adding-the-table-markdown-from-documentation-to-qa) is the optimal dupe target.