# Remove the tables and inline versions from the formatting help

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, markdown, help-center

On the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page, there are sections about tables and inline versions, which are only available in documentation. Since [documentation is being removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/4284627) and nobody can edit documentation anymore, I don't see the need of keeping documentation-specific markdown features on the formatting help page.

Also, instead of removing the part about tables, I think it would be better to add the table markdown to Q&A as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/349538). This has already been [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) though, so I don't have much hope in it being implemented. I would just like to point out that the reason why it was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) is because it would allow users to break the page layout, but if they could fix that in documentation, they should also be able to fix that in Q&A. Besides, [it's already possible to break the page layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297160/349538). [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328989/4284627) already asks for that feature, I just thought I would mention it here since it's related.

Anyway, please remove the documentation-specific parts from the formatting help page since they are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docs-specific Markdown help will be gone with the next production build.